# Smoke alarms wont stop going off at night

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, noise, smoke-detectors

So I'm a maintenance technician for a property, the issue that I am having is that the Smoke alarms in one of our units sets off all the other smoke alarms in the unit, we started by replacing all 4 batteries to all 4 smoke alarms, when that didn't work,we ended up replacing the entire system for the smoke alarms with brand new smoke alarms including the wiring, this worked for about 3 weeks and then the resident notified us the the smoke alarms continues to go off randomly at night only, and not a chirp like it sounds off and the rest follow, I just don't understand why this is happening when we have exhausted all possibilities, can anyone help me with this issue, brand new smoke alarms and brand new batteries

Comment: If these are AC smokes with a battery backup, have you verified that they’re getting AC power?

Comment: Try contacting the manufacturer of the alarms and asking this question.  They should be able to point out the source of the problem.

Comment: Could there be a backdraft issue at night that pulls exhaust gas in? More heating and less outside ventilation might do it. Are they combination alarms that detect CO?

Comment: Are there smokers or bad cooks in the building?